# Entity Framework 7 and Conditional Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

A legacy database I'm working with used a pattern like

```
CREATE TABLE [Document](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EntityTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,  -- Tells us if the document is for a item, person, company....
    [EntityID] [bigint] NOT NULL,   -- Is the primary key value from the item, person, company table
    [Url] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
)
```

There is no FK defined in the document table since each record could be describing data related to a different parent table.

Example:

Document table

| ID | EntityTypeID | EntityID | Url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | 123 | ... |
| 3 | 2 | 123 | ... |
| 4 | 2 | 123 | ... |
| 5 | 3 | 567 | ... |
| 6 | 3 | 456 | ... |

Person table

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Dave |

Item table

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Headphones |

Company Table

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 567 | Acme |
| 456 | Globlex |

Say the EntityTypeIDs are defined as Person = 1, Item = 2, and Company = 3. Then

```
Document.ID 1 and 2 are Dave's documents
Document.ID 3 and 4 are documents about Headphones  
Document.ID 5 are documents for Acme
Document.ID 6 are documents for Globlex
```

My first thought was to create views for PersonDocument, ItemDocument and CompanyDocument
and in OnModelCreating do something like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonDocument>(entity => 
{
  ...
  entity.HasOne(d => d.Person).WithMany(p => p.PersonDocument).HasForeignKey(d => d.EntityId);
  ...
 }
```

That works for reading the data and populating my DTO classes but I don't know if I could update or create new Document records using that approach.

When I try to add a document I get

`The entity type 'PersonDocument' is not mapped to a table, therefore the entities cannot be persisted to the database. Call ToTable`

How do I handle this?

Comment: I've struggled a lot with these *polymorphic associations* in the past. My final conclusion is: create a table per entity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: You can model this as a `Table-Per-Hierachy`, with a generic type, which I've written about in other answers. Let me know if you want me to dig through and find an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion that it is better for you to have a table documents and have tables that specify which document this is related to(PersonDocumet,CompanyDocumet,ItemDocument), so that you can have a control.

when you insert data ,step1 :insert to document then insert to related to other table

Dcoument:
Id,Url

Person Dcoument:

DocumentId,
PersonID

---

CompanyDocumet:

DocumentId,
CompanyID

---

ItemDocument:

DocumentId,
ItemID

Comment: We are going the create a table per entity route. There are only about a dozen tables using these 'polymorphic associations'

Answer (score 0):

As you are working on a legacy system, you need to ensure that existing functionality remains intact.
It is better to have separate tables for each type of document, though this can be tricky to manage existing data.
Another way to handle this scenario is separate methods to insert/Update related to(PersonDocument, CompanyDocument, and ItemDocument) and you need to call the methods by applying business logic.